# GNUPG, GPG, PGP, GPG4WIN, OpenPGP difference

Tags: gnupg

I have some questions.
What are differences between terms: gnupg, gpg, pgp, gpg4win, openpgp?
Is that algorithm, encryption software or what?
What are differences between them?
What of that terms are algorithms, and what is software?
And with what of these terms we can encrypt files or software?

Answer (score 3):

PGP is Pretty Good Privacy, a standard of asymmetric encryption.

GPG is GnuPG.

GnuPG is GNU Privacy Guard, a realisation of PGP.

GPG4Win is GnuPG recompiled for windows (and if i'm not mistaken it also has some extra applications to make it easier to work).

OpenPGP is another realisation of PGP.